# How to bind library function to reactjs class/content

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm all new to ReactJS, and it's pretty cool. One thing that is unclear for me, however, is how to use third-party libraries and their DOM functions with React. My current case is that I use [jQuery custom content scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) which manipulates a DOM element with this:

```
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('./#element').mCustomScrollbar();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

My issue is that it doesn't attach it self to my ReactJS element, which is:

```
var ChatBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var chatMessages = this.props.data.map(function (msgObj) {
      return (
        <ChatBoxMessage user_name={msgObj.user.name} timestamp={msgObj.timestamp}>
          {msgObj.message}
        </ChatBoxMessage>
      );
    });
    return (
        <div className="log log--chat">
            <ul>    
                {chatMessages}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Now, if I use `$('.log--chat').mCustomScrollbar();` in the console, it works fine, so all my stuff is loaded correctly, but I can't get it to attach it self to the element by it self.

What is the general practice going around this? Do I bind it in the actual React class somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *"I can't get it to attach it self to the element by it self"*. But this could be what you're after for:

```
...
componentDidMount: function() {
  var node = React.findDOMNode(this);
  $(node).mCustomScrollbar();
}
...
```

Comment: I meant that it could not bind it self, and rebind it self when it re-rendered. But you are exactly right, thanks my good sir - have a nice monday :)!